# CSS style attribute left blank

Tags: javascript, css, css-cascade

What happens when a CSS property like `transform` is left empty, i.e.

```js
element.style.transform = "";
```

check this fiddle-
https://jsfiddle.net/e85odhjf/

In the javascript part, i left the left.style.transform="" in the back() function(controlled by onmouseout) , so it brought back the shape to the original form.

Answer (score 1):

When you clear a declaration from a style attribute, you are removing a [declared value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#declared):

> Each property declaration [applied to an element](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#filtering) contributes a
>   *declared value* for that property associated with the element. See [Filtering Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#filtering) for details.

Moreover, that's a declared value with high [specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascade-specificity):

> Each declaration has the same specificity as the style rule it appears
>   in. For the purpose of this step, declarations that do not belong to a
>   style rule (such as the [contents of a style attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#interpret)) are
>   considered to have a specificity higher than any selector. The
>   declaration with the highest specificity wins.

Therefore, it's likely the value you are removing were the [cascaded value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascaded):

> The *cascaded value* represents the result of [the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascade): it is
>   the [declared value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#declared-value) that wins the cascade (is sorted first in the
>   [output of the cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#output-of-the-cascade)).

In that case, all the [cascaded](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#cascaded), [specified](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#specified), [computed](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#computed) and [used](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#used) values may change.

If there is no other declared value, the output of the cascade will be an empty list, and there will be no cascaded value. Then the specified value will be the result of the [defaulting processes](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#defaulting).

In your case, since `transform` is not an inherited property, its initial value will be used. That is, `transform: none`. That will "bring back the shape to the original form".